# how to print the delete key result enum as string

Tags: rust, redis

I am delete a key from redis when using rust, this is part of the code looks like:

```
pub async fn del_redis_key(key: &str,) -> Result<()> {
    let config_redis_string = get_config("redisConnectionStr");
    let redis_con_string: &str = config_redis_string.as_str();
    let redis_client = redis::Client::open(redis_con_string).expect("can create redis client");
    let mut redis_conn = get_con(redis_client);
    let mut redis_conn_unwrap = redis_conn.unwrap();
    let del_result = redis_conn_unwrap.del(key).map_err(RedisCMDError)?;
    FromRedisValue::from_redis_value(&del_result).map_err(|e| RedisTypeError(e).into())
}
```

now I want to output the delete result `del_result` as a string, I have tried to convert the result as a json string like this:

```
let result_json = serde_json::to_string(&del_result).unwrap();
println!("{}",result_json);
```

it seems did not work because the third party redis lib `Value` did not implement the serialize trait, the Value code looks like:

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq, Clone)]
pub enum Value {
    /// A nil response from the server.
    Nil,
    /// An integer response.  Note that there are a few situations
    /// in which redis actually returns a string for an integer which
    /// is why this library generally treats integers and strings
    /// the same for all numeric responses.
    Int(i64),
    /// An arbitary binary data.
    Data(Vec<u8>),
    /// A bulk response of more data.  This is generally used by redis
    /// to express nested structures.
    Bulk(Vec<Value>),
    /// A status response.
    Status(String),
    /// A status response which represents the string "OK".
    Okay,
}
```

is it possible to output the delete result as a string so that I could output into log? I am using the redis lib `redis = "0.21.3"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serde can actually derive for remote structures. Check this link for details: https://serde.rs/remote-derive.html

But in your particular example, things get a bit more tricky. Because the `Value` type is recursive (`Bulk(Vec<Value>)`) and [currently you cannot use `#[serde(with = ...)]` inside a `Vec`](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/723).

A way out is to define your own serializing function for the whole `Vec<Value>` type. Here is an example: https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1211

I've implemented this method for you. It is not quite straightforward though.

```rust
use redis::Value;
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Serialize)]
#[serde(remote = "Value")]
pub enum ValueRef {
    Nil,
    Int(i64),
    Data(Vec<u8>),
    #[serde(with = "redis_value_vec")]
    Bulk(Vec<Value>),
    Status(String),
    Okay,
}

mod redis_value_vec {
    use super::ValueRef;
    use redis::Value;
    use serde::{Serialize, Serializer};

    pub fn serialize<S: Serializer>(array: &[Value], serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error> {
        #[derive(Serialize)]
        struct W<'a>(#[serde(with = "ValueRef")] &'a Value);

        serializer.collect_seq(array.iter().map(W))
    }
}

fn main() {
    #[derive(Serialize)]
    struct W<'a>(#[serde(with = "ValueRef")] &'a Value);

    let val = Value::Nil;
    println!("{}", serde_json::to_string(&W(&val)).unwrap());
}
```

I suggest you submit a PR to that crate, adding a `serde` feature, optionally enabling this derive. This is very common.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is print out the result for logging purposes, `Value` [implements](https://docs.rs/redis/0.21.6/redis/enum.Value.html#impl-Debug-for-Value) `Debug`. So you can print it out with the debug format specifier:

```
println!("{:?}", del_result);
```